# VSLAM based navigation with Kinect, where do I begin?

Tags: ros, navigation, uav, kinect, vslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm interested in developing a robot (UAV) indoor navigation system basing on a MS Kinect (or Kinect-like, like the [PrimeSense dev kit](http://www.primesense.com/?p=514)) sensor. I'm specifically interested in corridor following.

I've recently bought a [BeagleBoard-xM](http://beagleboard.org/hardware-xM) platform and installed Ubuntu and ROS on it. I'd like to start off without any flying platform and implement the navigation layer first. So here is my plan (and questions):

1. I have to buy a sensor for VSLAM (ie. Kinect or so): do you have any suggestions on which one should I choose? I unfortunately wasn't able to connect PrimeSense recently, is it even worth it, or should I stick with the original Kinect?
2. Which stacks should I start playing with? I'm particularly interested in indoor navigation and attitude estimation (I could fuse with [IMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_measurement_unit) based attitude data afterwards).
3. I would then try to implement a distributed system (Desktop PC + BB-xM) via ROS, with both peers doing a part of calculations. How would you design such a system, what potential risks do you see right away?

Any suggestions welcome, tom.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9087/vslam-based-navigation-with-kinect,-where-do-i-begin?/) by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1079 on 2011-02-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-02-17**:
when you see an answer you like, mark it as an accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*I have to buy a sensor for VSLAM (ie. Kinect or so): do you have any suggestions on which one should I choose? I unfortunately wasn't able to connect PrimeSense recently, is it even worth it, or should I stick with the original Kinect?*

I was also unable to get a Primesense SDK from them directly, however you might want to continue trying as the Primesense device is quite a bit smaller, lighter, and less power hungry than a Kinect (which certainly has to be a good thing for a UAV).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-02-18**:
I only got one by winning one in the ROS 3D Contest

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-02-17**:
Thanks fergs, and is there a way to get a Primesense SDK indirectly anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. You could start with the Kinect and have a look what Patrick has done in the 3D contest. [altitude control](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/Quadrotor%20Altitude%20Control%20and%20Obstacle%20Avoidance) However as your onboard resources are limited (unless you're able to compute on the pointclouds from the internal DSP, I'm very interested in this, but I have no time) a combination of a regular camera and ultrasonic height measurement will do just fine I guess.
   We'll probably have some thesis students working on this also.
2. Look at this question + ansers: [monocular VSLAM](http://answers.ros.org/question/60/slam-with-one-camera)
3. Look at this question: [kinect-data-via-router-to-host-pc](http://answers.ros.org/question/220/kinect-data-via-router-to-host-pc) and my answer: [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/220/kinect-data-via-router-to-host-pc?answer=399#399)

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-03-02**:
Using DSP would be great, I don't know if it's possible on xM with Ubuntu though, see the information about a bug in xM here: http://elinux.org/BeagleBoardUbuntu#DSP . I don't know how to understand this, whether a hardware or a software error is causing problems. I'll read more when I have time...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. ASUS are supposed to be releasing the [Xtion PRO Developer Kit](http://cebit2011.asus.com/press-release/asus-reveals-the-worlds-first-motion-sensing-experience-for-pc/), an Primesense SDK based device. It may be easier to obtain than the Primesense SDK. [Details are sketchy](http://www.ubergizmo.com/2011/01/wavi-xtion-asus-primesense/) for a Q2 2011 release.  Note that some photos show it without the color sensor (ie. depth only).
2. Have you tried playing with the [RGBD-6D-SLAM entry](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/RGBD-6D-SLAM) in the recent OpenNI competition?
3. Given bandwidth limitations, you may want to decimate the point cloud. [This tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros/Tutorials/VoxelGrid%20filtering) may be a good starting point.

---

Originally posted by [rreid](https://answers.ros.org/users/323/rreid/) with karma: 124 on 2011-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1